# Backbone - View has no method 'get'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Hi, folks!**

I just started to learn Backbone, and I have a problem with my first code. The example code that I made have a button that, once is clicked, adds a piece of code (View), that should get some default values from the model. But I getting a message that says: `Object function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'get'`. Here is my code:

```
  var app = {};

  // the model
  app.Answer = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      title: 'Your answer here',
      isAnswer: false
    }
  });

  //the collection
  app.AnswerList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Answer,
    localStorage: new Store("backbone-answers")
  });

  //the view that is added when the button is clicked    
  app.AnswerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    // template: _.template($('#answer-template').html()),
    template: _.template('<%= title %>: <%= isAnswer %>'),

    events: {
      'click button.destroy': 'remove',
    },

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render','remove');
      // this.model.bind('change', this.render());
      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      $(this.el).html(this.template({title: this.model.get('title'), isAnswer: this.model.get('isAnswer')}));
      return this;
    },
    remove: function(){
      $(this.el).destroy();
    }
  });

  // the main view
  app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#body'),

    events: {
      'click button#insert-button': 'addAnswer'
    },

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'addAnswer');
      this.ul = $('#content');
      this.collection = new app.AnswerList();
      console.log('initialize');
    },
    addAnswer: function(){
      console.log('append');
      var newAnswer = new app.AnswerView({model: app.Answer});
      $('ul',this.el).append(newAnswer);
    }

  });

  app.appView = new app.AppView();
```

I'm a newbie in Backbone, so my question is: what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The model you pass to your app.AnswerView instantiation should be an instance of your app.Answer model, not a reference to the constructor function.

Comment: Hi, @kinakuta, thanks for the tip! You said, this part: `var newAnswer = new app.AnswerView({model: app.Answer});`, right? If I just put `var newAnswer = new app.AnswerView();`, I get this error: `Cannot call method 'get' of undefined`. But If I put `var newAnswer = new app.AnswerView({model: new app.Answer});`, I got no error, but the view is not appended. You know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var answer = new app.Answer();
var newAnswer = new app.AnswerView({model: answer});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vadim! With your example I see what @kinakuta mean, too! I just didn't created an instance of the model before add it to a view. I saw @Sebastian code too, but analyzing both methods, I see that your example returns a correct sequence of `cid` (client id) for the objects (`cid:view3`,`cid:view4`,`cid:view5`...), while the @Sebastian approach returns a sequence that "jumps" a number (`cid:view3`, `cid:view5`, `cid:view7`...). I don't know the consequences of this, but I prefer this method with correct numbers for `cid`'s.

Answer (score 1):

try with this code.
You must be instantiated the model when create a new view.

```
var app = {};

  // the model
  app.Answer = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      title: 'Your answer here',
      isAnswer: false
    }
  });

  //the collection
  app.AnswerList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Answer,
    localStorage: new Store("backbone-answers")
  });

  //the view that is added when the button is clicked    
  app.AnswerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    // template: _.template($('#answer-template').html()),
    template: _.template('<%= title %>: <%= isAnswer %>'),

    events: {
      'click button.destroy': 'remove',
    },

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render','remove');
      // this.model.bind('change', this.render());
      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      $(this.el).html(this.template({title: this.model.get('title'), isAnswer: this.model.get('isAnswer')}));
      return this;
    },
    remove: function(){
      $(this.el).destroy();
    }
  });

  // the main view
  app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#body'),

    events: {
      'click button#insert-button': 'addAnswer'
    },

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'addAnswer');
      this.ul = $('#content');
      this.collection = new app.AnswerList();
      console.log('initialize');
    },
    addAnswer: function(){
      console.log('append');
      var newAnswer = new app.AnswerView({model: new app.Answer()});
      $('ul',this.el).append(newAnswer);
    }

  });

  app.appView = new app.AppView();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Sebastian! Even though this works, I found that instantiating the model outside of the view, and then calling it (like @Vadim approach), returns a correct number of `cid`'s, which I prefer.